# How to Stream rtsp video which getting using live555 library to Wowza server which is running in local cloud

Tags: rtsp, wowza, live555

I have cross compiled live555 library for my android board and using that I can able to stream video board to any other device using rtsp protocol.

I have used "live555MediaServer" program for stream board to other devices. I got "rtsp" url and using that I am able to stream.

But now I want to push this video to wowza server which is running in our local cloud. while reading wowza document I found that you can use any supported encoder to stream video to wowza by registering wowza steaming engine in your encoder. I found following lines

- In your encoder, enter the following information, and then click Publish   or Start:
- Server URL: rtsp://[wowza-ip-address]:1935/live
- Stream Name: myStream
- User: publisherName
- password: [password]

so I want to know how can i register wowza ip with live555. In live555 is there any way we can register this wowza ip and stream video in wowza streaming engine ?

I found one application in "live555/testProgs/registerRTSPStream" while running this application with out any command line option it is showing below usage

```
usage: registerRTSPStream [-t] [-u <username> <password>] <remote-client-or-proxy-server-name-or-address> <remote-client-or-proxy-server-port-number> <rtsp-URL-to-register> [proxy-URL-suffix]
```

So Is it possible to register wowza server using this application and If yes then how to do it ?

Comment: Hi Pratik, did you get to the bottom of this? I am facing similar issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38745126/video-stream-nvr-to-wowza-cloud-instance. Thanks.